# How to use google search via SSH tunnel?

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, firewall, tunnel

I live behind the Great Firewall of China (not very proud of it) and I'm slightly technical. So I use SSH tunnel to route all connection to my VPS. (i.e. `ssh -D port` and then set `localhost:port` as a SOCKS proxy)

It works for me, however, Google thinks that I'm a bot. I see the following screenshot every time I try to search. It used to ask me to enter a captcha, but not anymore.

[image: Screen shot of Google]

Can anybody help? How do I bypass this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the VPS you are connecting to is (or has in the past) been used to do a lot of queries and Google doesn't like it.  You probably need to change the IP address you are connecting too.    [ I've used a SOCKS proxy exactly like you describe to not only do Google searches but to purchase stuff ].  The solution is probably to find another IP address/VPN  to use.

You might also want to look at the browser you are using - Google may not like the Referer string - but I suspect this is not where the problem lies.

Comment: I use Linode, I guess it's too popular for Chinese. I'm sure I'm not the only one who uses this as an SSH tunnel.

Comment: The problem is unlikely to be your distro, although it is possible your SSH connection is being MITM attacked and you getting redirected based on some kind of injection.  I would suspect this is unlikely -although definately possible.

Comment: You might also want to look at the browser you are using -- can you explain? How to check?